# Fix CSP policy using NODE JS

Tags: jquery, node.js, xss, content-security-policy

I'm working on web application using Node JS on my custom board. I use EJS template engine and JQuery.  My application used to work but no, after firmware update, I receve this warning on browser console: `Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘script-src-attr’` and others like `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://192.168.1.1:8080/jquery.min.js”.`
Also before firmware update I set CORS policyes like this:

```
//Enable CORS for all HTTP methods
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

This is my work directory:

```
-index.js
-API
   - Routers
   - Models
   - Controllers
-Views
   -Component
-Static
   - JS
   - CSS
```

I would not use 'cors' npm modules (if is not necessary).
I tried to change /static path and I tried to change ' res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" ' but but I think it is quite permissive. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Error or warning? What browser?

Comment: Try using [CORS](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware. Only one line required :)

Comment: This isn't a CORS problem. It's a CSP problem. You'd be wise to edit your question. And, what do you mean by "firmware update"?

Comment: I edit my question following you suggests. For the moment I prefer don't use middleware if is possible. When I run my application on “https://192.168.1.1:8080/home, it cannot load JS and CSS library and so my applciation is not usable. Server side the are not errors. Firmware udpate means cross-compile OS and dowload on my board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a CORS issue, but Content Security Policy. After updating firmware you have somewhere CSP header issued, try to find:

```
res.header("Content-Security-Policy", "... script-src-attr ...");
```

and remove the '-attr' part. Firefox does not support *script-src-attr* directive, it's support only *script-src* one.

If you do not need to use Content-Security-Policy, just remove this header, because wrongly configured CSP will blocks scripts, styles, fonts, images etc.

May be your web-server publishes this header. Check in the browser dev tool which HTTP headers have you get from server.